# Java Script: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am sorry if I this questions is duplication, I have read all the Q & A in the site regarding but did not find the answer.

I am getting the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. The funny thing is this is coming for only 1 client.
I have created a place where we can enter arrival and departure information of client but once when we are adding the one client it is coming for others it is working fine.
I have checked in all the computers in my office but still I can not add Mr. XYZ to arrival list.

This is the line

```
var fldQPRArrivalFlightID=document.getElementsByName('fldQPRArrivalFlightID['+fldCustomerReservationID+']['+mycount+']')[0].value;
```

Comment: Can you post your html too

Comment: that means 'fldQPRArrivalFlightID['+fldCustomerReservationID+']['+mycount+']')[0] is not defined. You have to use the browser debugger to find out the current values of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

the method `getElementsByName(..)` doesnt return an array - or an empty array. Therefore, `getElementsByName(..)[0]` is `undefined` and you'll receive the error.

You can try logging the returnvalue of `'fldQPRArrivalFlightID['+fldCustomerReservationID+']['+mycount+']'` and verify what the invocation of `getElementsByName( returnvalue )` should return.

Instead of your code:

```
fldQPRArrivalFlightID=document.getElementsByName('fldQPRArrivalFlightID['+fldCustomerReservationID+']['+mycount+']')[0].value;
```

Try

```
console.log( fldCustomerReservationID );
console.log( mycount );
console.log( 'fldQPRArrivalFlightID['+fldCustomerReservationID+']['+mycount+']' );
console.log( document.getElementsByName('fldQPRArrivalFlightID['+fldCustomerReservationID+']['+mycount+']') );
```

I'm actually surprised all this quoting goes right.

Comment: I am really sorry but I have found the answer,
The name I was trying to had an "Apostrophe" ('), later only realized.
But still cant enter the name is having Apostrophe ;-(